# Filter rows in Oracle select query (and not script or procedure)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have code in my Oracle stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(EMP_ID) INTO A_VARIABLE 
FROM STUDENT;

IF (A_VARIABLE > 0) THEN
   SELECT *  FROM DEPARTMENT1;
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT2;
END IF;
```

Basically I have to do this same filtration of rows in my SQL query (and not in the procedure or script).

Can anyone help with this Oracle query?

I have tried multiple solutions, but I'm not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

For 19c (19.7 and above) you may use [`SQL_MACRO(table)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/newft/sql-macros-sqm.html) feature and inline function declaration.

But different output structure of the same query is somewhat misleading, so I would recommend to use `union all` approach and align columns of two tables.

Below is an example for SQL Macro.

Setup:

> ```
> create table table1
> as
> select
>   level as id,
>   level as val
> from dual
> connect by level < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> create table table2
> as
> select
>   level as id,
>   lpad(level, 4, '0') as val,
>   dbms_random.string('x', 5) as str2
> from dual
> connect by level < 4
> ```
>
> ```
> create table decision
> as
> select 'Y' as res
> from dual
> ```

Run 1:

> ```
> with function f_decide_table
> return varchar2
> sql_macro(table)
> as
>   l_res varchar2(100);
> begin
>   select
>     coalesce (
>       max(q'[select * from table1]'),
>       q'[select * from table2]'
>     )
>
>     into l_res
>   from decision;
>
>   return l_res;
> end;
>
> select *
> from f_decide_table()
> order by 1
> ```

| ID | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

Run 2:

> ```
> truncate table decision
> ```
>
> ```
> with function f_decide_table
> return varchar2
> sql_macro(table)
> as
>   l_res varchar2(100);
> begin
>   select
>     coalesce (
>       max(q'[select * from table1]'),
>       q'[select * from table2]'
>     )
>
>     into l_res
>   from decision;
>
>   return l_res;
> end;
>
> select *
> from f_decide_table()
> order by 1
> ```

| ID | VAL | STR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | DGNY9 |
| 2 | 0002 | UHFYH |
| 3 | 0003 | EU12B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tHdmud0w)

Answer (score 1):

Sample `student` table; depending on course students take, *main query* will return data from one table (or another).

SQL> select * from student;

```
    ID NAME   COURSE
```

---

```
     1 Little Web
     2 Foot   Web

SQL> select * from department1;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

SQL> select * from department2;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Query uses a CTE that counts rows in `student` table; it is then used in `exists` subquery for two *similar* `select` statements which fetch rows from one of `departments` tables.

Currently, nobody is in IT so departments2 table it is:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select count(*) cnt
  3     from student
  4     where course = 'IT')
  5  --
  6  select * from department1
  7  where exists (select null from temp
  8                where cnt > 0
  9               )
 10  union all
 11  select * from department2
 12  where exists (select null from temp
 13                where cnt = 0
 14               );

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

However, if someone studies IT, `department1` will provide data:

```
SQL> update student set course = 'IT' where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from student;

        ID NAME   COURSE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 Little IT
         2 Foot   Web

SQL> with temp as
  2    (select count(*) cnt
  3     from student
  4     where course = 'IT')
  5  --
  6  select * from department1
  7  where exists (select null from temp
  8                where cnt > 0
  9               )
 10  union all
 11  select * from department2
 12  where exists (select null from temp
 13                where cnt = 0
 14               );

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this really helped. but that if department1 and department2 have different fields and different data types. in that case union will not work

Comment: basically if count >0 then i need to fetch all records from table 1 else i need to fetch all records from table 2

Comment: For UNION to work, columns must match in number (i.e. both queries have to select same number of columns) and datatype. If tables have different description and you can't match them, then this option won't work. As you want to do *everything* in a single query, I don't know whether you have any other option. If you wanted to use PL/SQL option, you'd e.g. create a function that returns refcursor (whose source is one of those tables) but - you said you want pure SQL option.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing to what you want to do (using just sql) would mean that you need to know all the column names and datatypes in both tables.
Next, you would have to do the datatype conversion for one union query as you have to select same number of columns with same datatypes.
The result would have all that you need but with some empty columns (those that do exist in other table but not in one you are selecting from).
Depending on total number of columns and on differences in names and types this coulld becomee too complicated and you realy shoud think about some function and reference queries.

Anyway, lets create some sample data to work with:

```sql
WITH        -- sample data
    students (ID, A_NAME) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'Mark' From Dual
        ), 
    dept_1 (ID, DEPT_NAME, DEPT_CITY) AS
        (
            Select '10', 'HR', 'NEW_YORK' From Dual Union All
            Select '20', 'IT', 'BOSTON'   From Dual 
        ),
    dept_2 (ID, DEPARTMENT) AS
        (
            Select 30, 'SALES'      From Dual Union All
            Select 40, 'PRODUCTION' From Dual 
        ),
--  dept_1 has 3 columns (ID VARCHAR)  -  same column name different datatype
--  dept_2 has 2 columns (ID NUMBER)
--  The rest of the columns have different names and same datatype
```

1. create cte (namings)  -  forcing union of rows for all columns from both tables - dummy filling non existant and converting To_Char(ID) to get same datatype (this is needed for union to work)

```sql
--  here are total  of 5 columns coded - it can be widen more if needed, this is just a sample to show handling of extra columns
    namings AS
        (
                SELECT  ROWNUM "RN", 'dept_1' "TABLE_NAME", Count(*) "CNT", To_Char(ID) "V1", DEPT_NAME "V2", DEPT_CITY "V3", 'X' "V4", 'X' "V5", 'ID' "C1", 'DEPT_NAME' "C2", 'DEPT_CITY' "C3", 'COL_X4' "C4", 'COL_X5' "C5"
                From    dept_1 
                Where   CASE WHEN (Select Count(*) "CNT" From students Where ID = 999) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
                Group By ROWNUM, ID, DEPT_NAME, DEPT_CITY
            Union All
                SELECT  ROWNUM "RN", 'dept_2' "TABLE_NAME", Count(*) "CNT", To_Char(ID) "V1", DEPARTMENT "V2", 'X' "V3", 'X' "V4", 'X' "V5", 'ID' "C1", 'DEPARTMENT' "C2", 'COL_X3' "C3", 'COL_X4' "C4", 'COL_X5' "C5"
                From    dept_2 
                Where   CASE WHEN (Select Count(*) "CNT" From students Where ID = 999) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0
                Group By ROWNUM,ID, DEPARTMENT
        ),
```

R e s u l t   when count from students = 0  (filtered out with where clause)

```sql
        RN TABLE_NAME        CNT V1                                       V2         V3       V4 V5 C1 C2         C3        C4     C5   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- -------- -- -- -- ---------- --------- ------ ------
         2 dept_2              1 40                                       PRODUCTION X        X  X  ID DEPARTMENT COL_X3    COL_X4 COL_X5 
         1 dept_2              1 30                                       SALES      X        X  X  ID DEPARTMENT COL_X3    COL_X4 COL_X5
```

R e s u l t   when count from students > 0

```sql
        RN TABLE_NAME        CNT V1                                       V2         V3       V4 V5 C1 C2         C3        C4     C5   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- -------- -- -- -- ---------- --------- ------ ------
         1 dept_1              1 10                                       HR         NEW_YORK X  X  ID DEPT_NAME  DEPT_CITY COL_X4 COL_X5 
         2 dept_1              1 20                                       IT         BOSTON   X  X  ID DEPT_NAME  DEPT_CITY COL_X4 COL_X5
```

2. create another cte (transposed) to unpivot the above data

```sql
    transposed AS
        (   SELECT * FROM namings
                UNPIVOT ( (NAMES, VALS) For COL_NAME IN( (C1, V1), (C2, V2), (C3, V3), (C4, V4), (C5, V5) )   )
            WHERE VALS <>  'X'
        )
```

R e s u l t   when count from students = 0

```sql
        RN TABLE_NAME        CNT COL_NAME NAMES      VALS                                   
---------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
         2 dept_2              1 C1_V1    ID         40                                       
         2 dept_2              1 C2_V2    DEPARTMENT PRODUCTION                               
         1 dept_2              1 C1_V1    ID         30                                       
         1 dept_2              1 C2_V2    DEPARTMENT SALES
```

R e s u l t   when count from students > 0

```sql
        RN TABLE_NAME        CNT COL_NAME NAMES      VALS                                   
---------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 dept_1              1 C1_V1    ID         10                                       
         1 dept_1              1 C2_V2    DEPT_NAME  HR                                       
         1 dept_1              1 C3_V3    DEPT_CITY  NEW_YORK                                 
         2 dept_1              1 C1_V1    ID         20                                       
         2 dept_1              1 C2_V2    DEPT_NAME  IT                                       
         2 dept_1              1 C3_V3    DEPT_CITY  BOSTON
```

3. Main sql  - pivoting data to columns from both tables

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        RN, 
        TABLE_NAME,
        MAX(ID_V) OVER(Partition By RN) "ID",  
        MAX(DEPT_NAME_V) OVER(Partition By RN) "DEPT_NAME",
        MAX(DEPT_CITY_V) OVER(Partition By RN) "DEPT_CITY",
        MAX(DEPARTMENT_V) OVER(Partition By RN) "DEPARTMENT" 
    FROM (
            SELECT * FROM transposed
            PIVOT  (
                        COUNT(NAMES), MAX(VALS) "V" FOR NAMES IN('ID' "ID", 'DEPT_NAME' "DEPT_NAME", 'DEPT_CITY' "DEPT_CITY", 'DEPARTMENT' "DEPARTMENT")
                    )
        )
    ORDER BY RN
```

R e s u l t   when count from students = 0

```sql
        RN TABLE_NAME ID                                       DEPT_NAME                                DEPT_CITY                                DEPARTMENT                             
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
         1 dept_2     30                                                                                                                         SALES                                    
         2 dept_2     40                                                                                                                         PRODUCTION
```

R e s u l t   when count from students > 0

```sql
        RN TABLE_NAME ID                                       DEPT_NAME                                DEPT_CITY                                DEPARTMENT                             
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
         1 dept_1     10                                       HR                                       NEW_YORK                                                                          
         2 dept_1     20                                       IT                                       BOSTON
```